# Random Forest: Number of Bags vs. Number of Trees

Tags: random-forest, bagging

What are the differences between the number of bags and the number of trees in a Random Forest? For what I knew number of bags = number of tress in RF.

However, in certain packages such as RankLib, you have two parameters to tune: number of bags and number of tress, where number of trees refers to number of tress in each bag. How is it so?

Answer (score 1):

Bagging ([bootstrap aggregating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating)) is applicable to lots of other algorithms than random forests (of which it is an integral part.)  It refers to a variance reduction technique based on randomly sampling from the data with replacement, running whatever estimation algorithm is being used on each sample, and then combining (usually averaging) the results.

In a random forest, the estimation algorithm is a tree, so you will have one tree per "bag".  In RankLib, there are several algorithms, each of which is run on each "bag".  One of these algorithms is the MART algorithm (Multiple Additive Regression Trees), which is an implementation of the Gradient Boosting Machine algorithm.  The MART algorithm will create many trees (hence "Multiple") on each bag, hence the need to specify the number of trees per bag.  Random Forests itself is another algorithm in RankLib, and the number of trees per bag will be needed to tell the RF algorithm how many trees to build on each of the bagged data sets.

Comment: thanks. so if i am to tune the hyperparameter for Random Forest in RankLib, should I go for the 'number of bags' or 'the number of trees within a bag'?

Comment: I've expanded the answer to include addressing this point - "number of trees within a bag" is the way to go.

Comment: thanks. i assumed that when I increased the number of trees within a bag, i will get better result. however, this is not what i got. the precision of the model increased up to 500 trees and dropped onwards. any ideas why?

Comment: Which model, RF or RankLib?  (I assume the latter, but best to check...)

Comment: yeah, i am referring to RankLib.

Comment: That's really worth a separate question, since it gets into the details of how RankLib works, and I'm not so familiar with that.  For MART, though, in general, more trees is not always better - at some point you wind up overfitting, and it just gets worse as you add more trees.  This isn't so for Random Forests, where more trees is always better (although perhaps not noticeably so.)   It may be that MART is causing RankLib to have this problem, but again, that's worth posting as a separate question.

Comment: thanks. perhaps you are right. i think they are using MART to build the ensemble trees within Random Forest.